# Move Wordpress sidebar from top to left

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a blog section on my website and while the sidebar is displayed on the left side in the blog category list or latest posts page, **on a single post the sidebar is on top**.

I've had some problems with the single.php page so I've started again from scratch. So this is the latest posts page http://www.crossfitawac.com/blog/ and **when I click on a post title from the sidebar calendar widget I would like to display the single post the same as in the latest posts page**. I've tried to copy some lines from the "latest posts" page template but it didn't work out.

Here is the single.php http://pastebin.com/WM08wjri

Comment: Added bold to emphasize the problem description and the desired solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some errors with the code that you added. I changed it for you below in a way that should work and not get the divs tangled up:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="page-content" class="page-content">

    <section class="page-header" id="page-header">

        <div class="row">

            <!-- Begin Sidebar -->

            <div class="three columns">

                <div class="sidebar">

                    <?php dynamic_sidebar('Primary Sidebar'); ?>

                </div>

            </div>


            <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('nine columns'); ?>>


                <div class="post">

                    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

                    <?php the_content(); ?>

                </div>

            </article>


            <?php endwhile; ?>


        </div><!-- #main-content -->


    </section>

</div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the problem `< section class="page-header" id="page-header">`. That means you have used a section named page-header before the row. Try to use this markup http://pastebin.com/yZcg7RQj